# Vimeo fullscreen : video appears under the website's elements

Tags: javascript, html, video, vimeo, vimeo-player

I'm having a really strange issue with vimeo & html5 fullscreen player.

I have this code in my template :

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/91593219/?autoplay=1" width="100%" height="615" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups"></iframe>
```

The iframe loads fine, but when I click "fullscreen", the browser goes in fullscreen mode with the video appearing UNDER the site (I have relative and absolute divs visible while watching the video).

You can experiment this bug here : http://webrelais.net/pingpong/projet/proxipolis

Has anyone experienced this issue ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I know this is an old thread but it would be useful on posts like this to specify which browsers this is an issue in. I had a site where this was an issue in Safari 12.0.1, however it was not an issue in Chrome 70.0.3538.77

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by disabling `animate.css` style on the element which included my iframe.

Nevertheless, I tried with `z-index` modifying, jQuery for changing styles but nothing worked, the only one solution was removing Animate CSS class.

Comment: Had the same issue in Safari V 14.0.2, after removing css animation class, it works as expected in full screen mode

Answer (score 1):

Was the same bug in Safari (13.0.4). In my case parent div of an iframe had `will-change` property. Fullscreen works correct after I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look shows that it is related to CSS or Javascript for the  element - since removing the id for that element makes fullscreen video work in Chrome at least.

Solve the problem by isolating CSS and Javascript that you use for that element and you should be able to find what causes it.

Comment: Thank you Dull for your help. After many hours spent tracking this bug, I've understood that it is occured by "animate.css". So my solution is to remove all the animated classes when the user plays the video.

Comment: what is "animate.css" is???

Answer (score 0):

`animation-fill-mode: both;` in parent elements seems to cause this issue with fullscreen videos.

Comment: Yes, this definitely is the cause but what's the solution to fix?